# man calling nroff with invalid option -P

Tags: command-line, manpage

Whenever I try to open a `man` page, I receive an error:

```
$ man man
man: command exited with status 1: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/libexec/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/libexec/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=205n -rLT=205n -P -c -Tutf8)
```

Trying to understand which of these commands returned `1`, I ran them by hand and discovered that `nroff` complains about the `-P` option being invalid.

```
$ cat /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/libexec/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/libexec/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=205n -rLT=205n -P -c -Tutf8)
/usr/bin/nroff: invalid option -P
```

If I replace the capital `-P` with the lower `-p`, the command runs just fine and prints the corresponding manpage.

`/etc/manpath.config` doesn't appear to contain any options related to this.

What could I have accidentally broken to receive this error?

I have already verified that the hashes of `man` and `nroff` are identical with the versions installed on another system without the problem, therefore the binaries themselfes can't be broken.

Where would I configure the arguments `man` uses to call `nroff`?

As requested the output of `type -a man`:

```
$ type -a man
man is /usr/bin/man
man is /bin/man
```

The files `/usr/bin/man` and `/bin/man` are identical and running them produces the same errormessage.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` to your question.

Comment: … and please check if running `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man man` makes any different?

Comment: `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man man` makes no difference.

Comment: Found the solution thanks to you'r request for the `.bash.rc`. @Raffa

Answer (score 3):

Found the Issue thanks to @Raffa,

I am using `zsh`, but when I opened `bash` the issue persisted, so I thought I could rule out my `zsh.rc`. I did not consider that any environment variables would carry over when I start `bash` from `zsh`.

Specifically I added the line `export MANROFFOPT="-P -c"` after configuring colored manpages on my server running Arch and thought I might as well do the same for my PC. But since Arch uses a newer version of `nroff` things broke.
Then I didn't use man on my PC for a month and forgot about the changes I made.

Comment: Exporting a variable will make it globally available to all shells and not just local to its original shell as you have found out and starting Bash from within ZSH is not the culprit here, but rather `export …` is.